# PHP __destruct public variable

Tags: php, function, class, variables, global-variables

How can I use this way. I want to create a global variable with the last running function.

```
<?php
class test{
    public $number = null;
    public function __destruct(){
      $this->number = 5;
    }
}
$test = new test();
echo $test->number; // null
// How can I use this way.
?>
```

Comment: `__destruct` will be called when the object is no longer referenced and before the item is destroyed, so setting a instance variable makes no sense.  What do you really mean by *the last running function*

Comment: I know that, actually. So what is the __destruct alternative for this process?

Comment: In addition to what Nigel asked what is it that you are trying to accomplish with the use of __destruct?

Comment: function run(){
    $this->number = 5;
}
$test->number; // 5
->run(); I would like to do the above operation without this part. So when the process is finished.

Comment: Maybe you want `__construct()` ???

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm doing it with another method.